# NullReference Exception was unhandled by user code

Tags: vb.net, null

I don't understand why I'm getting the following error:

```
NullReference Exception was unhandled by user code
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

from the following code:

```
Dim repNumber As String

 If Not (gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo").ToString.Trim = Nothing) Then
            repNumber = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo").ToString.Trim
 Else
            MessageBox.Show("repNumber is empty!")
            repNumber = repCurrent
 End If
```

isn't what this line is doing? (verifying if if the value is NULL (or NOT NULL)):

```
If Not (gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo").ToString.Trim = Nothing) Then
```

(The previous line is the one giving me the error)

Comment: more than likely "gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo")" is returning nothing. You can't call ToString on nothing.

Comment: Maybe the function 'GetFocusedRowCellValue' is the one that's returning 'Nothing'

Comment: @Jeremy This was exactly it.

Answer (score -1):

"NULL" and "Nothing" are not the same thing....you need to do this.

```
Dim repNumber As String

     If (gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo") is dbnull.value) Then
           MessageBox.Show("repNumber is empty!")
           repNumber = repCurrent 
     Else
           repNumber = gridView.GetFocusedRowCellValue("RepNo").ToString.Trim
     End If
```

"Nothing" refers to an object that has not been instantiated...."Dbnull.value" refers to a Null Value read from the database....

Comment: I've tried the same code with Nothing and with dbnull.value.  It works with Nothing but not with dbnull.value .

Comment: did you use the word "is" instead of "="?

Comment: Yes, I had used the "is" instead of the "=", in both cases.

Comment: It could have to do with the order of evaluation...I have edited my answer..let me know if it works....Also, if you still have problems, put a breakpoint and let me know which line you are failing on.

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå  From MSDN. "When checking whether a reference (or nullable value type) variable is null, do not use = Nothing or <> Nothing. Always use Is Nothing or IsNot Nothing.' ----And also "Nothing differs from the DBNull object, which represents an uninitialized variant or a nonexistent database column."

SOURCE:  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx